# If-then / Select Case for date range defined in cell reference

Tags: vba, excel, select-case

I apologize for the newb question but have not found a solution online.  I am trying to do a simple if-then statement on date ranges in VBA.  My code (not working) thus far:

```
            LR = 52
            Set rngData = Range("D2:D" & LR)
            'define the data range to evaluate
            For Each rngCell In rngData
                Select Case rngCell.Value
                    Case Val(Range("'Some_dates'!O8").Value) To Val(Range("'Some_dates'!P8").Value): rngCell.Value = Range("'Some_dates'!N8").Value
                    Case Val(Range("'Some_dates'!O9").Value) To Val(Range("'Some_dates'!P9").Value): rngCell.Value = Range("'Some_dates'!N9").Value
                    Case Val(Range("'Some_dates'!O10").Value) To Val(Range("'Some_dates'!P10").Value): rngCell.Value = Range("'Some_dates'!N10").Value
                    Case Val(Range("'Some_dates'!O11").Value) To Val(Range("'Some_dates'!P11").Value): rngCell.Value = Range("'Some_dates'!N11").Value
                Case Else: rngCell.Value = "Outside date ranges"
                End Select
            Next rngCell
```

The output for all the cells is "Outside date ranges", which means it is choosing the "else" value for all the cells in rngData, which is incorrect.

Cells O8:P11 in the 'Some_dates' worksheet define four date ranges (start is column O and end is column P).  These are dates that can look like numbers or dates depending on how you format the cell.  Column N in the 'Some_dates' worksheet has labels for each date range.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If everything you are comparing is dates, then `Val` is the problem.  `Val(1/1/2012)`, where 1/1/2012 is a "real" Excel date (or a fake one for that matter) returns "1".  Val returns the beginning of a string up to the first non-numeric character.  So, try:

```
Case Range("'Some_dates'!O8").Value To Range("'Some_dates'!P8").Value: rngCell.Value = Range("'Some_dates'!N8").Value
```

Your code should work when the dates are stored in General or Number format, as then Val returns the entire number (string).